# Google Docs / Exel - need to know how to add formula

Tags: worksheet-function, google-docs

I'm using Google Docs / Exel and can't work out how or where to add a 'formula'.

I have a column "i" which is the number of items.  I have another column "j" which is the cost of those items.  Column "i" has various number of items and column "j" has varying prices.

So, in short I want column "k" to be the total of column "i" x column "j".

Any help in how / where to insert this formula is much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To add a formula to a cell, you put an equal sign (=) and then the formula. So, the formula for cell I1 times J1 would be:

`=I1*J1`

and would look like this:

[image: an example formula]

You could then copy-paste or fill-down this formula for as many rows of data as you have.

**Edit**: To fill-down a formula, drag the black box on the bottom-right corner down through your rows of data, like this:

[image: fill down explanation]

This copies the formula into each cell, replacing the row references with the appropriate row (row 2, row 3, etc.).